# "Sure another" vs "sure if another"

Tags: word-usage

I'm doubting myself b/c Google grammar is telling me to (there should be a word for this -- gramidiot?).

On topic, I wrote what I think is a grammatical sentence:

> I'm not sure another call is worth it.

Google grammar wants this to be:

> I'm not sure if another call is worth it.

I think both sentences are grammatically correct -- I don't think that interrogative "if" is necessary. I would welcome input on this subject. Thanks.

Comment: I'd probably say "*that* another".